# button click password validation using angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs

In my requirement I want to validate password and confirm it through a button. If I entered wrong my method doesn't call. if I entered correct only then will it works. I tried please help me to solve this problem this is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6jqmv68d/7/).

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl" >
    <form data-toggle="validator" role="form" name="myForm">Name<inputtype="text" id="name" ng-model="name" required/>Enter password<input type="password" id="txtInput" ng-model="password" required/>    <br />
    Confirm password:  <input type="password" id="txtInput" ng-model="confirmpassword" required/>

    <button  class="btn btn-default" style="background-color: #005baa; color: #fff;"  ng-click=" myForm.$valid && submit()">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope){
    $scope.submit=function(){
    alert("hi");
    var password = document.getElementById("password")
    , confirm_password = document.getElementById("confirm_password");

    function validatePassword() {
        if (password.value != confirm_password.value) {
            confirm_password.setCustomValidity("Passwords Don't Match");
           return true;
        } else {
            confirm_password.setCustomValidity('');

        }
    }
}
  var _CeqObj = new Object();
  _CeqObj.Name = $scope.name;
  _CeqObj.Password = $scope.password;
  _CeqObj.Meth = "AB";
  var httpreq = $http({
         method: 'POST',
         url: "api/Home",
         data: _CeqObj
      }).success(function (response) {
         if (response == "success") {
           alert("Thank You");
      }
      else {
           alert("error");
      }
});});
```

Comment: You have errors in your console. `ReferenceError: $http is not defined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't call your $scope function submit() because it sends a regular submit() form.

Then, use angular to get inputs. In the controller you can use $scope.myNgModel to get data.

Here is a clean code to handle your confirm :

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.submitForm = function() {
        if ($scope.password != $scope.confirmpassword) {
            alert("Passwords Don't Match");
        } else {
            doSomeStuff();
        }
    };

    function doSomeStuff() {
        alert("Password = " + $scope.password);
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6jqmv68d/10/